# In Angular v4, is it possible to use the Google translator API to send it text, and receive a translation?

Tags: ajax, angular, google-translate

And if it is, how? I'm learning webapp stuff. And I'm trying to make a translator. I already setup my html to receive an input string. But now I don't know how to proceed. I'm looking through the google translate api documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate-translate-text-java) and I see some stuff for Node but I'm not sure if that would work for Angular. What am I supposed to import? A friend mentioned ajax requests, how would I go about that?

Any help or pointing in a good direction would be very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, if you do a POST request using Angular's HTTP client. See: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text#translate-translate-text-protocol for information on what you need to send in your POST.

Comment: If you haven't already, I would highly recommend working through the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial on Angular.io: https://angular.io/tutorial the last chapter deals with making HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 component.TS
......................................

ngAfterViewInit() {
        var v = document.createElement("script");
        v.type = "text/javascript";
        v.innerHTML = "function googleTranslateElementInit() { new google.translate.TranslateElement({ pageLanguage: 'en' }, 'google_translate_element'); } ";
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(v);
        var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.type = "text/javascript";
        s.src = "//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit";
        this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
    }
```

```html
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you closer, using the Angular HttpClient to send a Get with parameters but you'll have to do additional work to load your API key and handle an authorization response. Please do the Angular tutorial as mentioned first. https://angular.io/tutorial

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-ex5

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
 selector: 'my-app',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})

export class AppComponent  {
apiKey = ''
url = 'https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate';
result: any;
q: any;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}  

translate(): void {
 let params = new HttpParams();
 params = params.append('q', this.q);
 params = params.append('target', 'es');
 params = params.append('key ', this.apiKey);

 this.http.get(this.url, {params: params})
   .subscribe(response => this.result = response);
```

}

Comment: Thank you so much. Going through the tutorial right now, but this was very helpful as well.

Comment: Hey, so I'm dealing with the apiKey, I'm not sure which of the fields from the json file that google provides I should use.  They have a field private_key_id and private_key (which is much longer). I've tried both, just copying and pasting the values unto the code so that the apiKey equals that value from the google json file, but I get the following error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

What am I missing here? thanks

Comment: So I got the key from google. Figured that out, but now i still get the access-control-allow-origin error. What could it be?

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' means the origin IP Address of the request is not authorized to access the server. You'll have to go into your Google API config and select Credentials then 'Create client ID' for a Web Application and add an "authorized JavaScript origin" which is the IP Address of your source.

Comment: I did it. Still getting the same error. I've been reading about CORS. Do you maybe know about how to implement that? Again, thanks for all the help!

Comment: CORS is always going to be a problem if the client originates from a different source than the server. I don't know of any good way around this when making requests from the client, only hacks like JSONP (see https://angular.io/api/http/Jsonp) or browser extensions.

Comment: So it's only possible to make the call from the backend then?